# Asp.net MVC 3 Razor code problem in a if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following asp.net mvc 3 razor code, where "item" is my model,

```
<a @if (item.Selected) { class="youarehere" } href="@item.Href" title="@item.Title">@item.Description</a>
```

This code throws up the following error,

```
CS1513: } expected
```

which is pointing to

```
class="youarehere"
```

portion of the code, but I could not figure out why.  Could someone help point out how to fix it please?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a @if (item.Selected) { @:class="youarehere" } 
 href="@item.Href" 
 title="@item.Title">
 @item.Description
</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it seems to treat the '}' as part of the '@:' =/ (and putting a '@' in front of the bracket doesn't help either.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
<a @(item.Selected ? "class='youarehere'" : "") href="@item.Href" ...
```